# Can't change settings in VSCode Jupyter editor because vertical scrollbar active area is only a pixel or two wide

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to change some settings in VSCode.  As a start, the vertical scrollbar active area is only a pixel or two wide.  It typically takes me 3-4 tries before I successfully grab/drag it.  No problems, I'll change the Vertical Scrollbar Size.  I did -- and nothing changed.  I exited and restarted, nothing changed.  I tried changing another setting (Scrollbar: Scroll By Page) and nothing changed.

@modified shows all the settings I've changed.  They just don't work.  (Edit:  I kept experimenting, and I found some settings DO work, e.g. Cursor Style and Auto Closing Quote.)

What's the secret to get the changes to work ??

Version 1.74.2, 1 day ago.  Running on Windows 10 Pro.

====================

So, the settings work in the normal editor but not in the Jupyter editor, which is where I actually work 95% of the time.  I can't find a scrollbar-width setting for the Notebook class.  Does anyone know if the scrollbars can be adjusted in Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Are your changes in user settings or workspace? Also can you include the settings changes in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure which I worked in originally, but I have discovered that the Workspace settings DO work -- but not for Jupyter workspaces or the Settings editor!  The scrollbar width is an Editor setting, and apparently a Jupyter notebook is not considered an Editor.  User settings seem to have no effect.  The settings ARE in the question -- I was trying to set the Vertical Scrollbar Size and Scroll By Page.